# Bootstrap 5 pop over content is not displaying

Tags: laravel-8, bootstrap-5, popover

I am using bootstrap 5 popover in laravel 8 , as per the bootstrap 5 syntax i have use `data-bs-toggle="popover"` , and have added the title in same but my content is in application.js file ,how can i call the content to blade file in pop over ,
I have tried the following

```
<div class="span5 col-md-3">
<a id="timezone" class="btn btn-primary editable"
data-bs-toggle="popover"
data-bs-container="body"
title="Time Zone"
data-bs-content="">GET</a>
</div>

<script>
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, {html: true})
});

</script>
```

The pop up is working , only title is displaying and not the content , On inspect i can see the content :[image]

[image]

So i can i get the content on my pop over ?